# Use Transaction with New-Item

Tags: powershell

Trying to execute the following...

```
Start-Transaction
New-Item -Name dogshit.txt -UseTransaction -Path '~\happy_place'
```

When I do, I get a love note stating, "The provider does not support transactions." I'm saddened because the help page for `New-Item` shows a "UseTransaction" parameter with description "Includes the command in the active transaction. This parameter is valid only when a transaction is in progress."

Why-o-why won't the transaction work in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error indicates, the underlying provider that you're using `New-Item` against must support transactions.

Judging from the item name `dogshit.txt`, I'm assuming you're attempting to create a file, but unfortunately the `FileSystem` provider doesn't support transactions.

There is only one builtin provider that supports transactions - the `Registry` provider:

```
PS C:\> Get-PSProvider |? Capabilities -match 'Transactions'

Name                 Capabilities                         Drives
----                 ------------                         ------
Registry             ShouldProcess, Transactions          {HKLM, HKCU}
```

Comment: Ugh! That makes total sense. ...of course the file system provider doesn't support transaction.Thank you.